# AJAX callback: error with firefox

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I've a custom callback with a form which works well in last chrome and last FF.

```
$form['foo']['bar'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t(''),
  '#attributes' => ['class' => array('search-api glyphicon glyphicon-refresh btn-primary')],
  '#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::fetchApiData',
    'event' => 'click',
    'effect' => 'none',
    'progress' => [
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => NULL,
    ],
  ],
);
```

However, my customer has a old version of firefox, the **esr 45.9.0** version, and when we click on the button that trigger the callback, we have an alert error.

> An error occurred while attempting to process
>   /declaration?ajax_form=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax: invalid regular
>   expression flag a

Does anybody know how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related to drupal/boostrap theme. It doesn't occur with default drupal theme.
Replace methods in Attributes.cleanClass pass the identifier as a 3rd parameter isn't needed because string replacements in JS are chained.
[https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap/issues/2969106](http://Drupal%20boostrap%20patch)

Comment: Hello,thank you for your answer, i was about to comment the same thing.
Work perfectly without this theme and also with the patch which is linked.
Regards,